# In Google App Engine, how do you select entities where an attribute does not exist?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using the python version of GAE and extending models from db.Model, how do you fetch entities where an attribute equals None or does not exist?

```
#This works
#Fetch 10 entities where duration == 0.0
entities = MyModel.all().filter('duration = ', 0.0).fetch(10)

#This doesn't. How can I do the equivalent?
#Fetch 10 entities where duration == None
entities = MyModel.all().filter('duration = ', None).fetch(10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have entities without `duration` property (can't be filtered because index can't refer to them) and entities with `duration` set to None (can be filtered).

Since you have changed `MyModel` schema, you should fix the entities stored without `duration` property with something like this:

```
entities = MyModel.all()
for entity in entities :
  if not entity.duration :
    entity.duration = None
    entity.put()
```

Have a look to [appengine-mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) library to accomplish this long running task.

Comment: I am looking for a way to find only the entities missing the duration property. Is you opinion that the only way to do this is to first create duration=None on every entity? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since your entities are correctly updated, you can use the Query class to fetch them from Datastore (using duration = None). Without this fix, I think you can only filter using a clunky check "if not entity.duration: ..".

Answer (score 0):

I think the usual way to do this is to add a boolean flag field to your model and filter on that.  In your case, that would be something like

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    duration = db.FloatProperty()
    has_duration = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    # ... etc ...
```

where you could then do your second query with

```
entities = MyModel.all().filter('has_duration = ', False).fetch(10)
```

You'll have to take care to update the `has_duration` field when creating/editing your entities, though.

Comment: This isn't necessary: once entities have been stored with the new definition, you can filter on duration = None; before they've been updated, they don't have the new 'has_duration' flag either.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood the question slightly.